# bootstrap hambuger menu - menu items will not display unless hamburger button is pressed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

I am implementing a hamburger menu with bootstrap and following the generic code from the boot strap site, HOWEVER, as soon as I use `<ul>` tags, my menu items only appear when I hit the hamburger button.

This means that when I resize the page from `300px` to `1200px`, the hamburger button doesn't change back to the inline menu, but stays as a button the whole time.

Has anyone ever had this issue?

ps. I've noticed that when I remove the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags from the script, the menus appears normally in a horizontal fashion.

[menu WITHOUT ul or li tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5mMH.png)

[menu WITH ul or li tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JrZj.png)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a  href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="add_post.php">Add Post</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="add_category.php">Add Category</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="uploadFile.php">Upload File</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="logout.inc.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably because the bootstrap CSS or JS is not made to work with li or ul. Please review the CSS and scripts involved and make the changes needed to work with ul and li

Comment: Please share the relevant code - we cannot troubleshoot a screenshot.

Comment: any idea guys? anything would help